# Multiple @SessionAttributes in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, session-variables

I want to store multiple objects in SessionAttributes. I am able to store one object but not able to a find way to store multiple objects.

e.g
@SessionAttributes("XYZ")

Requirement: I have two pojo classes ,ABC and XYZ. I want to store objects of both classes in sessionatttributes.

Comment: specify it as an array. `@SessionAttributes({"XYZ", "ABC"})`.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum . This solution worked.